# SimpleDate Format parsing error

Tags: java, ionic-framework, simpledateformat, datetime-format

I'm getting this error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Apr 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"
```

I have used this `SimpleDateFormat` can any one suggest me a correct one?

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z (Z)");
```

Comment: Note: `IST` is also `Irish Standard Time`, `Iran Standard Time` and `Israeli Standard Time` I suggest you drop the `(IST)` at the end.

Comment: @Ravi : Did you check my answer? If it is working for you then accept+upvote it.

Comment: no! dude it's not working for me it's only give cast parse error

Comment: Did you try the same code?Your java version?

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeding date as "Fri Apr 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)". Then it's wrong. Please remove GMT. All time zones are calculated from GMT only.

Try passing date as "Fri Apr 08 2016 00:00:00 +0530 (IST)". It will work.

Comment: If it has worked then please accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Suggesting changing the input will often not work. The solution is usually to adapt the pattern, not the input which might come from external sources where the user has no power to change.

Answer (score 1):

The correct parse-able date string should be:

```
Fri Apr 08 2016 00:00:00 IST (+0530)
```

This little snippet should clear the confusion. It's the reverse of what you're doing:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z (Z)");

String strDate = format.format(new Date());
System.out.println(strDate);
```

Output is: `Fri Apr 08 2016 17:26:34 IST (+0530)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the pattern `EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)`

1) Using Java 1.6 :

```
System.out.println(fromStringToDate("Fri Apr 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)", "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)"));
```

> Output (in my system) : Fri Apr 08 00:00:00 IST 2016

Refer this link for timezone values [Java TimeZone List](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/)

```
public static Date fromStringToDate(String myPotentialDate,String pattern) throws Exception{
        // DateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        String countryCode = "US";
        String languageCode = "en";
        String timeZone = "Asia/Kolkata";
        DateFormat myDateFormat = getDateFormat(pattern,countryCode,languageCode,timeZone);
        // We set the Leniant to false
        myDateFormat.setLenient(false);
        try {
            return myDateFormat.parse(myPotentialDate);
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            // Unparsable date
            throw new Exception("Unparsable date '"+myPotentialDate+"' with pattern '"+pattern+"'. Due to '"+e+"'",e);
        }

    }

    private static DateFormat getDateFormat(String pattern,String countryCode,String languageCode,String timeZoneId){
        // We build the Local
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(languageCode,countryCode);
        // We build the DateFormat with the Local and the pattern
        DateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern,myLocale);
        // We set the TimeZone to the correct one
        myDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId));
        // We set the Leniant to false
        myDateFormat.setLenient(false);
        return myDateFormat;
    }
```

2)Using Java 1.8 [Java8 Date time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

```
        String countryCode = "US";
        String languageCode = "en";
        String timeZoneId = "Asia/Kolkata";

        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse("Fri Apr 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)").withLocale(new Locale(languageCode,countryCode)));
        ZoneId zoneId= ZoneId.of(timeZoneId); 
        ZonedDateTime zdt= ZonedDateTime.of(dt, zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdt);
```

Output:

> 2016-04-08T00:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

Comment: Hm, I cannot reproduce your output "Fri Apr 08 00:00:00 IST 2016". Instead, I get "Fri Apr 08 00:00:00 CEST 2016" in my timezone Europe/Berlin which is another instant 3 and half hours behind India. So the result is wrong. Have you really tested your code?

Comment: Hi. The OP asked he was not able to parse the date (Fri Apr 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)). So my answer is only to parse the given String. More over I have put the output just to tell him that I am able to parse the date.

Comment: I still get "Thu Apr 07 22:00:00 UTC 2016", tested on the website "https://www.compilejava.net/"

Comment: @Meno Hochschild Getting 'Thu Apr 07 18:30:00 UTC 2016' now

Comment: Can you please tell us your default locale and default timezone? Maybe also your Java version? This would probably help in order to analyze our different test results.

Comment: My Default Locale and Timezone are en_US,
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null] respectively and https://www.compilejava.net/ 's  default locale and Timezone's are en_US,
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null] respectively. So my system I am getting Fri Apr 08 00:00:00 IST 2016 and in https://www.compilejava.net/ I am getting Thu Apr 07 18:30:00 UTC 2016. So both date are equal. I am using Java6

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to investigate more details on this weekend and try to reproduce your tests..

Comment: @MenoHochschild No problem. It was nice discussion with you.

Comment: @MenoHochschild: Why did you remove your answer?

Comment: Because of my statement about `SimpleDateFormat` (what the OP primarily asked for). The rest of the answer is okay but has only the character of a supplement. My new tests of `SimpleDateFormat`-code on different!!! workplaces have shown that the results seem to depend on the concrete Java-version or associated tzdb-version. My first test of `SimpleDateFormat` used v1.7.0_51. My second test confirmed your test result using Java-8-platform. Conclusion: `SimpleDateFormat` is somehow unreliable, but might work for OP on newest java-platform if the OP just takes more care of the format pattern.